# My dataGridView isnt updating when i have edited a row of values in a seperate form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView within a MainForm that is listing all the relevant data into it when the form loads.

When i want to go to edit a row. I select it and press edit, it then loads an EditForm. Here i can edit the data and save.

The information has been successfully edited and saved but the dataGridView isnt updating.

Is there an autoRefresh property i have not seen or a way to refresh it when closing the edit form?

***MainForm***

```
    private void EditAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    EditAdminForm Admin = new EditAdminForm();

    Admin.idTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Admin.usernameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Admin.firstnameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    Admin.surnameTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Admin.emailTxt.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    Admin.statusCombo.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    Admin.ShowDialog();

    }

    public void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'student_CBDataSetAdmin.Admin' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.adminTableAdapter.Fill(this.student_CBDataSetAdmin.Admin);

    }
```

***EditForm***

```
    private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //SQL Connection and SQL for updating admin information
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter sda3 = new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE Admin set Admin_Username='" + this.usernameTxt.Text + "' , Admin_FName='" + this.firstnameTxt.Text + "' , Admin_SName='" + this.surnameTxt.Text + "' , Admin_Email='" + this.emailTxt.Text + "', Admin_Status='" + this.statusCombo.Text + "' WHERE Admin_ID='" + this.idTxt.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    sda3.Fill(dt3);

    MessageBox.Show("Information Successfully Updated!");

    dt3.Clear();

    this.Close();

    }
```

[THIS IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE, GRIDVIEW SOURCE AND BINDING AT THE BOTTOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGcwn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending any reference to a databound object or whatever, you are copying the values from the datagridView into the popup, and then you are not doing anything with it.

You need to either return the dataTable when you are closing the popup, or manually call a refresh of your dataAdapter. This second option is easier though it requires one more trip to the database.

at the end of your EditAdminBtn_Click add`
EDIT: As per your screenshot, I see that you use a bindingSource. Once you've refreshed your dataTable you can reset the bindings

```
this.adminTableAdapter.Fill(this.student_CBDataSetAdmin.Admin);
AdminBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: I have added this to the end of editadmin button. Now do i have to create a return for the dataTable?

Comment: Normally you dont since you're already updating the data in the database, and you are just refreshing from the database once the edit is done

Comment: The thing is the datagridview isnt actually refreshing. So the edit has been made, its showing in my table with in the database that an edit has been made. but when opening the MainForm once edit form has closed. Its not showing the new value, only the old one.

Comment: Can you actually post more code, how do you bind the dataGridView to the values?

Comment: i have just used the toolbox to create my datagridview and it seems to have added its own binding

Comment: Included a photo at the bottom